# SQL-Duplicated rows Sql Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have a problem with this SQL statement it prints results with duplicated rows which is annoying here is my SQL statement :

```
SELECT
week_day,
exam_date ,
s.name ,
l.lgna_name
,f.first_name
FROM
fci_exam_time_table_line,
fci_subject s ,
fci_staff f,
lgna_lgna l 
WHERE
exam_id =%d 
GROUP BY
week_day,
exam_date ,
s.name ,
l.lgna_name ,
f.first_name
ORDER BY
exam_date
```

and it prints like below

```
week_day|  exam_date |name|lgna_name|first_name

"monday";"2015-04-13";"12";   "12"  ;"12"
"monday";"2015-04-13";"12";   "12"  ;"323"
"monday";"2015-04-13";"12";   "232" ;"12"
"monday";"2015-04-13";"12";   "232" ;"323"
"monday";"2015-04-14";"12";   "12"  ;"12"
"monday";"2015-04-14";"12";   "12"  ;"323"
"monday";"2015-04-14";"12";   "232" ;"12"
"monday";"2015-04-14";"12";   "232" ;"323"
```

and i want it to print this like:

```
week_day|  exam_date |name|lgna_name|first_name

"monday";"2015-04-13";"12";   "12"  ;"12,323"
"monday";"2015-04-13";"12";   "232";"12,323"
"monday";"2015-04-14";"12";   "12"  ;"12,323"
"monday";"2015-04-14";"12";   "232" ;"12,323"
```

Comment: Try putting in some join conditions.

Comment: could you tell me how ?

Comment: `GROUP BY exam_date` and `GROUP_CONCAT(first_name)`

Comment: nice ..could you tell me the equivalent in postgersql ??

Comment: i have same database in both (mysql and postgres) running in 2 machines

Comment: The duplicates are due to the complete lack of join conditions. Your question is lacking basic information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Group_Concat` Function and remove the `f.first_name` from `Group by`

```
SELECT week_day, 
       exam_date, 
       s.name, 
       l.lgna_name, 
       Group_conact(f.first_name, ',') 
FROM   fci_exam_time_table_line, 
       fci_subject s, 
       fci_staff f, 
       lgna_lgna l 
WHERE  exam_id =% d 
GROUP  BY week_day, 
          exam_date, 
          s.name, 
          l.lgna_name 
ORDER  BY exam_date
```

For `Postgres` use `array_to_string` and `array_agg`. For explanation check [here](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/group-concat)

```
select ...
       array_to_string(array_agg(f.first_name), ',')
FROM   fci_exam_time_table_line, 
       fci_subject s, 
       fci_staff f, 
       lgna_lgna l 
WHERE  exam_id =% d 
GROUP  BY week_day, 
          exam_date, 
          s.name, 
          l.lgna_name 
ORDER  BY exam_date
```

Comment: could you post   the equivalent in postgersql ?

Comment: This is just putting lipstick on the pig that this fundamentally broken query is. The tables need to be joined properly. Cross-joining four tables is extremely expensive nonsense.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - based on the sample data clearly this is the solution

Comment: @Fireblade: This is a very bad, potentially dangerous example. Nobody should use that. A cross join of four tables can stall your server if you have more than a few rows in each. Just add join conditions. The question is lacking basic information to fix the query.